# Dump fails to re-create index over array of hstore column

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-10

I'm dumping a large database with `pg_dump -O -U <user> <db> >dump.sql`.

[Here is the gist of dump.sql](https://gist.github.com/svoop/0eda35d364d31e4b032a60ec406b42ba) with everything irrelevant stripped.

When importing the dump into another Postgres instance (identical setup) with `psql -f dump.sql -U <user> <db>`, the following error happens on the `CREATE INDEX` line 147:

```
psql:dumped.sql:147: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 5:           element hstore;
                          ^
QUERY:
        DECLARE
          arrHstore ALIAS FOR $1;
          key ALIAS FOR $2;
          element hstore;
          string text;
        BEGIN
          FOREACH element IN ARRAY arrHstore LOOP
            string := concat(string, ' ', element->key);
          END LOOP;
          RETURN trim(leading from string, ' ');
        END;

CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "immutable_array_to_string" near line 5
```

So everything but the final `CREATE INDEX` has worked.

Now I connect to the database with `psql -U <user> <db>` and paste the previously failing `CREATE INDEX` command... the index is created without any problem.

A few things I've tried:

- Dumping only the structure with `--schema-only` creates a dump that imports just fine. The problem only occurs if there is at least one row inserted as part of the dump.
- I tend to rule out owner/permissions as the cause because I create the dump with `-O`.
- This particular index is years old and similar dumps have worked fine until recently. Therefore, it might be related to upgrading to Postgres 10.3. However, I have no easy way to test the dump on older versions since it's not downwards compatible.

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the security fixes concerning the `public` schema in the latest point release of PostgreSQL.

Either change the function so that it refers to the type `hstore` with its schema: `public.hstore`, or add `SET search_path = public` to the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

To schema-qualify the `hstore` operator `->`, you can replace

```
element -> key
```

with

```
element OPERATOR(public.->) key
```

Similar for other operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint! I've changed `element hstore` to `element public.hstore`, however, creating the index fails with `ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.hstore -> character varying` and `LINE 1: SELECT concat(string, ' ', element->key)`. It seems, I'm still missing something here.

Comment: I figured it out myself just when you posted the solution here, thanks again!!